# jquery-ui dialog password already filled at open

Tags: passwords, jquery-ui-dialog

As wanted, dialog box for login is opened, but password is already filled in, although I put password field with value=""

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Connexion aux données">
        <form>
            <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
                <br>
                    <div>Nom du foyer</div>
                    <input type="text" name="foyer" id="foyer" value="" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><br>
                    <div>Mot de passe</div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><br>
                    <div style="font-size:0.6em;padding-top:6px;">Afficher les caractères</div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="reveal" id="reveal" value="" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:20px;">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and Jquery code in head part

```
    var $dialog = $( "#dialog" )
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        close: function(event,ui) {
            $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
             }
        });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
```

I have also cleaned browser cache but nothing changed.

[image]

By clicking on reveal checkbox I saw password is the same I have used in previous dev for testing few months ago.

Why this happens and how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me too. After debugging I found out that it was the password that browser had saved and it was loading it onto the password field on page load.

After clearing the saved password, I was able to get the empty password textbox.

This could be the case with you too.